# Run python function once usb is mounted

Tags: python-3

I'm currently having a problem on how can I run a python function once the user mounts a flash drive. I have a GUI that's in idle mode and the user can start using when he/she plugs a flash drive. Your help will be very much appreciated :) [image]

Comment: This previous answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115731/linux-usb-connect-disconnect-event#7951860

Comment: It isn't really specific for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You should give it a try and post what you did so that we can make suggestions based on that.

Comment: One way to achieve that is called "udev rules".

Comment: Hello again! The flash drive can be recognized now using pyudev. I'm moving on to my next problem which is how to change the content displayed when a flash drive is detected. Thank you guys for your help! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run python script with boot so it'll be running all time

Here is a example code that ejects when any usb mounted. You can edit the code to make what you want :

```
'''
Usage: python3 usb_eject.py
OS: Window7 and later
Eject the usb storage when the usb device plugin your PC!
'''
from time import sleep
import http.client
import subprocess

def monitorUSBStorage():
label = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S',
'T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
monitorDisk = []
for i in label:
    try:
        file = open(i+':/')
    except Exception as e:
        '''
        error = 2  =>not found
        error = 13 =>permission denied (exist!)
        '''
        if(e.errno == 13):
            print("Disk : "+i+" Exist!")
        else:
            monitorDisk.append(i)

print("Start monitoring.....")
while(True):
    print("Check...")
    isININ = False;
    disk = '';
    for i in monitorDisk:
        try:
            file = open(i+':/')
        except Exception as e:
            if(e.errno == 13):
                print("Disk : "+i+" Exist!")
                isININ = True
                disk = i
                break
    if(isININ):
        tmpFile = open('tmp.ps1','w')
        tmpFile.write('$driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application\n')
        tmpFile.write('$driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("'+disk+':").InvokeVerb("Eject")')
        tmpFile.close()
        process = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy','Unrestricted','./tmp.ps1'])
        process.communicate()
    #sleep for 2 seconds
    sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitorUSBStorage()
```

To use it in raspi you can change usb listing command by the light of [that topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=165203)

- Code is from Github/iamgyz [Link](https://github.com/iamgyz/usbEjector/blob/master/usb_eject.py)